# average value to the nearest quarter

Tags: python, math

I am new to python and trying to make function that will calculate the average value of inputs,how can I modify my function so it will return float to the nearest quarter 0.25 i.e the output can only be `x.0` `x.25` `x.50` `x.75`, I wrote the following function but I am not sure how to go next

```
def calculate_average(*args):
    total = sum(args)
    avg = total/len(args)
    return avg
```

example of output

```
#calculate_average(30,35,15) -> 26.25
#calculate_average(20,28,14) -> 20.75
#calculate_average(1,2,3) -> 2.0
```

Comment: Check the `round()` function. Multiply your number you want to round with 4, round to the nearest whole number, and then divide that by 4 again.

Comment: `return round(avg * 4) / 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a custom function to round to nearest quarter.

```
In [34]: def quarter_round(x):
    ...:     print(round(x*4)/4)
    ...:

In [35]: def calculate_average(*args):
    ...:     total = sum(args)
    ...:     avg = total/len(args)
    ...:     return avg
    ...:

In [36]: quarter_round(calculate_average(4,9,3))
5.25

In [37]:
```